# Nginx Reverse Proxy messing up the request for PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-rds

I have a PostgreSQL RDS instance on a private subnet in a Amazon VPC. I'm using an instance on a public subnet in same VPC to reverse-proxy requests to EC2 and RDS instances on the private subnets.

Reverse-proxy works well with HTTP to EC2 instances. However, I'm not able to connect to the RDS instance through the reverse-proxy.

I am able to connect to the RDS using `psql` from the EC2 instance on the public subnet. However, if I reverse-proxy, I get this error:

```
> psql --host=PUBLIC_IP --port=5432
psql: received invalid response to SSL negotiation: H

nginx access log: 
[PUBLIC_IP] - - [17/Apr/2018:10:51:45 +0000] "\x00\x00\x00\x08\x04\xD2\x16/" 400 174 "-" "-" "-"
```

I get the same error if I just try another HTTP port:

```
> psql --host=[PUBLIC_IP] --port=80
psql: received invalid response to SSL negotiation: H

nginx access log: 
[PUBLIC_IP] - - [17/Apr/2018:10:51:45 +0000] "\x00\x00\x00\x08\x04\xD2\x16/" 400 174 "-" "-" "-"
```

I also get the same error if I try `localhost` from the public EC2 instance:

```
> psql --host=localhost --port=5432 
psql: received invalid response to SSL negotiation: H

nginx access log: 
[PUBLIC_IP] - - [17/Apr/2018:10:51:45 +0000] "\x00\x00\x00\x08\x04\xD2\x16/" 400 174 "-" "-" "-"
```

However, doing direct connection from public EC2 instance to the RDS in the private subnet works fine:

```
> psql --host=postgis-database.REDACTED.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432
Password:
```

So it seems plausible that nginx is messing up the connection and forwarding wrong headers or IP's or something? H

What is the fix or workaround for this? How to forward exact same connection content through nginx? And can this be due to Connection "close" that nginx attaches?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Not really, ended up doing SSH tunnels instead.